# Как добавить pip в переменные среды Windows 11?

Tags: python, pip

Когда я ввожу `pip install python-tk`, cmd говорит что такой команды нет. Я посмотрел в интернете и узнал, что чтобы это убрать и чтобы pip работал нужно добавить его в переменные среды. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вот тут написано https://it-tehnik.ru/windows10/nastroyka/peremennye-sredy.html

Comment: Я с этим не заморачиваюсь - набирайте `py -m pip install python-tk`. Особенно полезно, если несколько версий питона, например `py -3.8 -m pip install python-tk` и т.д.